# Enviar string via bluetooth no Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Android que envia uma string com o valor `ola` pelo bluetooth.

Como faço para enviar `ola` pelo bluetooth para um endereço específico como `00:00:00:00:00:00`?

Uma função que faz o envio de uma string pelo bluetooth para um endereço específico seria de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, bom amigo!

Tente isso:

```
private OutputStream outputStream;
private InputStream inStream;

private void init() throws IOException {
    BluetoothAdapter blueAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (blueAdapter != null) {
        if (blueAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = blueAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            if(bondedDevices.size() > 0){
                BluetoothDevice[] devices = (BluetoothDevice[]) bondedDevices.toArray();
                BluetoothDevice device = devices[0];
                ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
                BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
                socket.connect();
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                inStream = socket.getInputStream();
            }

            Log.e("erro", "Dispositivos não estão conectados.");
        }else{
            Log.e("error", "Bluetooth está desligado.");
        }
    }
}

public void write(String s) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
}

public void run() {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytes = 0;
    int b = BUFFER_SIZE;

    while (true) {
        try {
            bytes = inStream.read(buffer, bytes, BUFFER_SIZE - bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

A fonte deste código está [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899475/android-sample-bluetooth-code-to-send-a-simple-string-via-bluetooth).